# how to set height of a div in % , even if I use <!DOCTYPE>?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, doctype

Is it possible to set the **height** of a **div** in **percentage** , even I  am using the `<!doctype>` ?

My **jsp** page was already fully designed without **doctype** and created lots of **div's** dynamically. The **div** height was given in **%** only .

But now i forced to add the **doctype** to get work the `jquery dialog box` and some other **jquery plugins** ?

**My need :**

1. How should I make the div height to work in **percentage %** , even I added the `<!DOCTYPE>` ?

Hope our stack users will help me.

Comment: what exactly is the problem with using a doctype? (hint: if you haven't got a doctype, your page will be in quirks mode which has been obsolete for over a decade)

Comment: My jsp page fully designed without doctype.But i need to add the doctype to get work the jquery dialog box ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the **solution** by adding the below code in my **css** , even I have the 
`<doctype>` in my `JSP`,

**Solution one :**

```
html,body {

   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;

}
```

**Solution two :**

1. set the **div css** to `absolute`

Answer (score 1):

The use of a `<!doctype>` will ensure the browser knows what HTML version you are using.

Not using the `<!doctype>` will result in the browser using it's own defaults, resulting in a low cross browser compatibility. It could work well in IE9 and not in IE10, or well in Safari and not in Chrome etc...

It's highly recomended to always use a `<!doctype>`

Comment: But my situation and full design was already devloped with out doctype ? Now I need to add doctype for jquery ?

Comment: @KitePlayer Then you need to get with the times. Add a `<!DOCTYPE>`, find out what breaks because it was obsolete, and fix it.

Comment: Yes, especially if it's an old application. I have the same issue where I am working now. It was developped for IE5, without doctype, and they want it to work now in any browser :S. No magic, all HTML, CSS, and javascript must be reworked ;(

Comment: `+1` for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that a *lot* of things will break if you don't have a doctype. That includes jQueryUI. If you want to use modern browser features and javascript libraries, then you **must** have a valid doctype.

This really isn't an option; the doctype tells the browser to go into standards mode. Without it, it'll be in quirks mode, which has been obsolete for well over a decade. Modern Javascript libraries simply aren't designed to work in this mode.

So the question becomes how to add a doctype without breaking your page layout?

If you've got a site that was designed without a doctype, there are a number of things that will be different when you add a doctype, but the main one is the box model. This determines how element widths work in conjunction with `padding`, `margin` and `border`. The old Quirks mode box model is quite different to modern standards mode, and your layout will be affected.

Fortunately, you can fix this very very easily: Add the following to your CSS code:

```
* {box-sizing:border-box;}
```

This will tell your page to use the old style box model, even in standards mode. Your page layout should now look a lot better with the doctype.

There are other layout differences that may affect you, but that's the biggest one, and also the easiest to fix. Start with that, and then see what else is still wrong; it should be fairly simple to deal with the remaining issues as you see them.

I hope that helps. If you have further problems, try searching this site (and the wider internet) for more help converting from Quirks mode to Standards mode -- it's a common question, so you should find plenty of help.

Answer (score 1):

If you give `absolute` positioning to the div you can give height for the Div

Comment: Thanks for the info.But I already know this. anyway `+1` for your answer.